# Apache 2 forward request IP address to virtual host

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am having an Apache server which is running on port 80 and a Tomcat server running on port 8080.

I am forwarding the requests coming for a certain domain to Tomcat using a virtual host in Apache using the below configuration.

In Tomcat, for logging and security purposes you need the IP address of the remote host which I am always getting as localhost (127.0.0.1). I need to get the remote IP address as there are attacks from some IP addresses.

Is there another way to implement this on Ubuntu if it is not possible with Apache virtual hosts?

The config file for Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com
  ProxyPreserveHost   On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/myapp/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you checked the `X-Forwarded-For` header in your application?

Comment: nope trying out now

Comment: @MichaelHampton its working with X-forwarded-For